# How to clear a value from an inline row, such as DateInlineRow?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, eureka-forms

If I use the DateInlineRow or any other inline row, there is no way to clear the value. How can this be done?

Comment: what you mean with "there is no way to clear the value"? what you need to do?

Comment: If I use the DateInlineRow and choose a date from the picker. How can I then clear/remove that value so it is empty? I want to remove the date value.

Comment: you want clear after selection? is that what you need?

Comment: check  my answer and give me some feedback, regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had been working in your question, I will use `DateInlineRow` as example

**if you want to clear the value**

```
   <<< DateInlineRow(){
        $0.tag = "inlineDateTime"
        }.cellSetup({ (dateCell, dateTimeRow) in
        // Setup the start date
        let currentDate = NSDate() as Date
        dateTimeRow.dateFormatter?.dateStyle = .short
        dateTimeRow.dateFormatter?.timeStyle = .short
        dateTimeRow.value = currentDate
        dateCell.textLabel?.text = "" //if you want clear the value in creation
    }).onCellSelection({ (cell, row) in
        row.cell.textLabel?.text = "" //if you want clear the value in cell selection
    }).onChange({ (row) in
        row.cell.textLabel?.text = "" //if you want clear the value on value change
    })
```

**If you want to clear the value in some other button**

**Search by tag and set the value of the row to `nil`**

```
if let dateTimeInlineRow = self.form.rowBy(tag: "inlineDateTime") as? DateInlineRow
                    {
                        if let baseCellText = dateTimeInlineRow.baseCell as? Cell<Date>
                        {
                            baseCellText.row.value = nil
                            baseCellText.update()
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: Yes, you could do it on that way. I was more into have a feature like the little cross button that you could have for a regular input field.

Comment: Say that the user has a saved form with data. One of this fields is an DateInlineRow with an date. Now the user want to remove that date value and save.

Comment: use the search by tag section @sverin